# Why does 'this.username' in my Sequelize model return a 'Potentially invalid usage of this' warning but other fields do not?

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, sequelize.js, warnings

If I rename the username attribute, the error goes away. 'username' sets this warning off for whatever reason though, which to me is a bit of a headscratcher. I am using IntelliJ Ultimate. Is this perhaps just IDE specific and am I safe to ignore that warning?

```
username: {
  type: DataTypes.STRING,
  allowNull: false,
  validate: {
    len: [2, 32],
    notNull: true,
  },
  get() {
    return this.getDataValue('username');
  }
},
fullUsername: {
  type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
  get() {
    return `${this.username}#${this.discriminator}`;
  },
  set() {
    throw new Error("user field is not settable.");
  }
},
discriminator: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
  validate: {
    min: 4,
    max: 4,
    notNull: true,
  }
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside getters you should always use `getDataValue` to avoid potential recursive calls when one getter uses another one and vice versa.

```js
fullUsername: {
  type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL,
  get() {
    return `${this.getDataValue('username')}#${this.getDataValue('discriminator')}`;
  },
  set() {
    throw new Error("user field is not settable.");
  }
},
```

Comment: Yeah good point, overlooked that honestly. However, it still gives the error when doing a class-wide getter. It just doesn't like the word username for some reason.